# Glass Material ussues

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine, glass

Greetings to the forum members, I work with glass materials, and there are some problems with them. There are problems on different rendering engines. On Eevee, the glass material does not work in corner, and on Cycles there are problems with the display. Screenshots below. On the image render, the problems are still the same. I will be grateful if you help.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Edit**: Thanks everyone, solution: "In Eevee you need to enable the Render > Screen Space Reflections > Refraction option, and the Material > Settings > Screen Space Refraction"

[image]

Comment: In Eevee you need to enable the Render > Screen Space Reflections > Refraction option, and the Material > Settings > Screen Space Refractions

Comment: You should turn on screenspace reflections and also select referaction in it too. Also in the material settings. Make sure that your blend mode is something other than opaque. If this doesn't work, is it possible for you to share your file? If yes, plz do.

Comment: Thank you, now it works.

Comment: Do not edit the solution into your question, this will not make the question appear as solved. You can write an answer to your own question and after some time accept it as correct. But your question also states: "on Cycles there are problems with the display", are these problems resolved as well (apart from that I do not see any issues in the screenshot because I do not know what is there in the scene that might be causing what you are pointing at)?